# What is the purpose of cloud code on Parse when working with a database?

Tags: javascript, android, deployment, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So my android app is successfully able to add data to the parse database but I am being prompted to deploy some cloud code to start scheduling jobs on my data.

I can query the db effectively from the app through the parse api and so I am very unclear on why I am required to write a javascript program. What is the advantage. The sample on the website is a "hello world" app so I don't understand how this relates to my android app?

appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the idea of [thin client](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_client) and also the [security reasons](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/parse-security-iv-ahead-in-the-cloud/) that leads to using cloud code. And I think it is not mandatory to use cloud code. It is up to you